# How could I modify the ssh_config file on a linux host with perl?

Tags: perl, ssh

I have a interesting problem, my script uses ssh to access my vmware server in order to pull data from it. I have discovered that if the machine running the script has never connected to the server the script will fail to run because the question asking if the host I am connected to should be added to my known hosts file.

Based on reading some forums and such and people having a similar issue I came up with an idea. I wanted to modify the `ssh_config` file on the "script host" to exclude known host checking for the host that specified in the config file. This would be done by the config script I have made that ask you various questions that generate the xml config file.

Now for the problem...

I need modify the config file, I was thinking the easiest would be slurp the file into perl and manipulate it. Slurping I have done before but according to what I have read the directive for disabling certain ssh options on a perticular host has to go before the global options directive.

How can I insert text in between 2 blocks of text in the current file?

This is what my ssh_config looks like

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

**--This is what my modification need to go--**

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2,1
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
```

Comment: Why not just use `ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no` in your script?

Comment: Because I am using the module Net::OpenSSH. Also I don't want modify it globally just for the specific host. The latter being more of a reason.

Comment: just suck it up and ssh once and type "yes". The check is there for your protection.

Comment: Yes I understand the check is there for a reason but the intention of my script is that you are connecting not only to a machine on your LAN but also to machine that your trust. So yes the initial fix is easy I would like to remove any involvment of the user having to modify something, I am to be as fully automated as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the lines of a file via a Perl array with the core [`Tie::File`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aFile) module. For example, to insert a line using offset:

```
use Tie::File;
tie @array, 'Tie::File', $file or die "Can't tie $file";
splice @array, $offset, 0, $line;
```

You can also loop through the array, etc. Changes to the array are reflected in the file immediately.

Comment: Then what? Dump the array back to a file line by line with a loop?

Comment: Hmmm I seem to be having trouble getting Tie::File to build, it keeps fail a bunch of the tests. Make won't build it. Plan B?

Comment: @Solignis: you don't need to install it, it's a core module.

Comment: Not on my system, it says it was not installed. I am running perl 5.10.1 on Debian 6. Anyhow I found a patch to fix the problem with the build. Make made the file so I should be able to install it.

Comment: Tie::File was first released with perl v5.7.3 according to [corelist](http://p3rl.org/corelist). It's also [packaged properly in Debian](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/all/perl-modules/filelist). Solignis, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Well either way it works. I can use the module. I just made a script based on the example above. Works great!

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to remove the changes I make the to file in the event the hostname or something changes